# How do I assign a static method to a delegate in C# via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider the following code:

```
internal delegate object FactoryMethod();
```

Now say I have the following code:

```
String myStaticMethod = "FooFactory.GetInstance()";
```

How do I do the following?

```
FactoryMethod myMethod = //A delegate pointing to FooFactory.GetInstance()
```

I'm googling away, but I can't seem to find a clean example or at least one that deals with static methods.

Comment: Do you really need reflection for this?

Comment: I'm not reflecting on anything, but I typically call it reflection when I'm doing stuff to code that is outside the norm such as creating an instance of a class via a String.

Answer (score 4):

Use one of overloads of the [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx). Here is one possible way:

```
var className = "FooFactory";
var methodName = "GetInstance";
var implType = Type.GetType(className);
var implMethod = implType.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[0]);
var res = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(FactoryMethod), implMethod);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found this:

```
typeof(YourClass).GetMethod("GetInstance", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```